# How to retrieve the current date and subsequent dates on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have rendered the following data using my API,where 0 is like {{x.count}} and today,tomorrow and subsequent days are from the {{x.day}} from API.

0 Appoinments Today

0 Appoinments Tomorrow

0 Appoinments Wednesday

0 Appoinments Thursday

0 Appoinments Friday

My HTML view is like the below:

```
<span ng-repeat="x in scheduledAppointments_report"><a ng-click="test(x.day);">{{x.count}} Appoinments {{x.day}}</a> <br/><br/></span>
```

I want to retrieve the date on respective hyperlink clicks.

Kindly let me know the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure this is what you want: <a href='#here' ng-click='get_date(x)' >click me</a> and add the get_date as function $scope.get_date = function(item) { return item.date }

Comment: I have done this.But how will retrieve date string from the day given in the API

Comment: can you show the scheduledAppointments_report json

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date Try {{ x | date }}

Comment: [{day: "Today", count: 0}, {day: "Tomorrow", count: 0}, {day: "Wednesday", count: 0},…]
0
:
{day: "Today", count: 0}
1
:
{day: "Tomorrow", count: 0}
2
:
{day: "Wednesday", count: 0}
3
:
{day: "Thursday", count: 0}
4
:
{day: "Friday", count: 0}

Comment: only the day values are given.Today,tommorrow and wednesday and so on for 5 days

Comment: I think you need to return a date or you can return day as 1or 2 like that can you do that

Comment: The values are coming from the API

Comment: Yes exactly.But i need a suggestion to retrieve the date

Comment: Is it possible to send the json data with a date field too from the api.

Comment: So you have not a date, just the name of the day. In this case you can consider Today = current date, Tomorrow = current day + 1, Wednesday = current day + 2 etc. I think you have this relation: the first item is list is the current day, then you increase the date with 1. $scope.today = new Date(); the x day: $scope.x_day = new Date(); $scope.x_day.setDate($scope.today.getDate() + x); Seems ok for you?

Comment: $scope.test = function(x_day,index){



        $scope.today = new Date();
        $scope.x_day = new Date();
        alert($scope.x_day);
        $scope.x_day.setDate($scope.today.getDate() + index);
        
    }

Comment: This always gives me the current date on click of any hyperlink

Comment: Put the alert($scope.x_day); after setting the date. Is is ok?

Comment: Please check my answer. I think it must be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyApp">
    <a href="#" ng-click="get_x_day_date(0)">Today</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="get_x_day_date(1)">Tomorrow</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the code:

```
function MyApp($scope) {
  $scope.today = new Date();
  $scope.get_x_day_date = function(index) {
    $scope.x_day = new Date();
    $scope.x_day.setDate($scope.today.getDate() + index);
    alert($scope.x_day);
    return $scope.x_day;
  }
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3agz0pw0/